# Truecrypt, killed process, still able to copy files on external disk

Tags: truecrypt

I have just started using TrueCrypt on the go to encrypt my entire external usb disk. Everything works nicely, now I just have one question:

I plug in the disk and mount it with TrueCrypt. I can copy files on to it and read it. All seems ok. Then I decide to kill the `autocrypt` process from running in the background and I can still write files on that disk.
Why is that?
Does it mean it will still be encrypting even though process isn't running anymore?

I'm talking about windows TrueCrypt on the go version.

OS: Windows 8.1

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why would you kill the process?

Comment: That is not the point. The point is, that disk is stil writable, eventhough the process is killed and program is closed. So i am not really sure how are files being encrypted then?

Comment: You didn't indicate what operating system.

Comment: It is windows 8.1

Comment: Feel free to update your question and the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI process only serves as a management interface for the kernel driver. This driver does all the heavy lifting, including encryption and decryption.

Bottom line: This is expected behavior. You can even close it normally while volumes are mounted IIRC.

Comment: Thanks. And this driver get loaded as soon as you mount the disk with truecrypt?

Comment: @vrocipes [The driver is always running.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MjiGd.png) You can see it in Device Manager when you enable the “Show hidden devices” option, in the “Non-Plug and Play Drivers” category.